# cmd /c and the & symbol in file path

Tags: windows, path, command, line

I ran into a problem, where I have a batch file located in a directory that has the and symbol in it.

When I try to run the cmd /c on the batch file the and symbol messes up the cmd program even though the path is double quoted.

```
C:\>cmd /c "C:\This & That\batch.bat"
'C:\This' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I'm not sure what to do. I tried escaping the & , using ^& but that doesn't seem to work as I'm all-ready in double quotes.

If I run the same command line from a directory that does not have an & symbol it works fine.

```
C:\>cmd /c "C:\This and That\batch.bat"

C:\>echo "Hi There"
"Hi There"
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so this would be the best way.

You also need to escape the `&` with `^` and run double double quotes.

```
cmd /c ""C:\This ^& That\batch.bat""
```

or you can set a location variable and use `&&` to run the `set` and `cmd /c` after each other.

```
set "location=C:\This ^& That" && cmd /c ""%location%\batch.bat""
```

Comment: Thanks I've flagged this as a solution as it has worked. I ended up working around this by setting the working directory first, and than running the batch file by name only ( without specifying the full path).